# How to remove unused temp files from Google Cloud SQL managed Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We've moved to Google Cloud SQL, created couple of databases and imported lots of data. Alongside it was a pretty large amount of queries which were interrupted here and there which have left some garbage in form of temp files. And the storage usage went far above 1TB.

```
postgres=> SELECT datname, temp_files AS "Temporary files", pg_size_pretty(temp_bytes) AS "Size of temporary files" FROM pg_stat_database;
    datname    | Temporary files | Size of temporary files 
---------------+-----------------+-------------------------
 cloudsqladmin |               0 | 0 bytes
 template0     |               0 | 0 bytes
 postgres      |               0 | 0 bytes
 template1     |               0 | 0 bytes
 first         |           33621 | 722 GB
 second        |               9 | 3399 MB
 third         |          293313 | 153 GB
(7 rows)
```

According to the results of the query above we have ~1TB of potentially useless files. There are couple of questions:

1. How to identify temp files not used by any running queries?
2. How to remove them having that postgres is managed by Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: Did you try listing contents of temp dir using [file access functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE)? Each temp file associated with session will have its pid in the name.

Comment: Great hint! Thanks! I wasn't aware about it. But question number 2 is still opened

Answer (score 2):

As per the PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW), the field `temp_bytes` is defined as:

> Total amount of data written to temporary files by queries in this
>   database. All temporary files are counted, regardless of why the
>   temporary file was created, and regardless of the log_temp_files
>   setting.

Meaning, that the number is the sum of the temporary file sizes since the **creation** of the database (or since last pg_stat_reset()), and **not** the current temp file usage.

The current usage could be determined using the 'file functions' in non-cloud database instance, but in Cloud SQL a normal user can not execute `select pg_ls_dir('base/pgsql_temp')` as this is reserved only to superusers.

As you said, Cloud SQL is a managed service, therefore at the moment, there is no way to see the current temp file usage.

One thing that will definitely clear the number you see is pg_stat_reset(), though as said before, it is not about current temp file usage, but a historical total;

One thing guaranteed to clean out temp files is **restarting** of the database instance, as part of the start process is wiping the `base/pgsql_temp` directory.

Comment: Nice hint as well, I'll check out how it would look like after instance restart