# Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

1) Does in any way logs generated by Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL service effects it's performance?

2) Second one my Cloud PostgreSQL instance have logs in TB. Is there any way to clean it?

Comment: How did you check that you have "TBs" of Logs in you PostgreSQL instance?

Comment: @NahuelVarela query like SELECT temp_files AS "Temporary files"
     , temp_bytes AS "Size of temporary files"
FROM   pg_stat_database db;

Comment: There is a grate answer to this in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595676/8889821

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove unused temp files from Google Cloud SQL managed Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556583/how-to-remove-unused-temp-files-from-google-cloud-sql-managed-postgres)